Two solid plus one stranded wire in a wire nut?
I want to replace an old outlet with a new one that has USB-A and USB-C 60w (https://leviton.com/products/t5634-w). The old outlet had another outlets daisy chained. So, the question is - can I take two solid wires (that were on the old outlet) and one stranded wire (from new outlet) and shove them into a wire nut and twist them?
Additional questions: do the wire nuts have to be in the gang box or they could be outside of it? Are there better solutions than wire nuts?


Thank you very much in advance!!

Your question about the nuts being in the gang box is unclear...how would they be outside the box when the cable has to come into the box?

The wires on the new outlet are fairly long, I was hoping to have just those in the box (since it will be tight for) and the wire nuts outside the box. I’m installing a new box, so I’ll look for a larger one (still has to be one gang though).

AFAIK all wire connections need to be accessible in the box—you can't shove them through the cable bushings or something.

Yes you can twist solid and stranded together and cover with a wire nut. (Wires should be twisted together, then be inserted in the wire nut, and the nut twisted further until tight. Do not just shove the wires in and expect the nut to twist them together.)  Be sure the wirenut is sized properly to hold all the wires and be covering any bare wire.
All wire terminations, nutted, sure-port, or on a device must be in a box.
Other than wire nuts, there are port connectors (commonly referred to as Wago connectors) that are approved for most applications now. Be sure to get those that are UL approved.
Look for the capacity of the box to be sure all the wires will fit.  You may need to install a larger box.

Perfect, thank you! I think I’ll try Wago and I do think I might need a larger box…

Most wire nut manufacturers specifically state that no wire pre-twisting is needed. And my experience confirms that, applying a wire nut will indeed twist the wires together.

@kreemoweet.  That said, I have never met an electrician that would not twist the wires with pliers prior to installing the nut.   Manufacturers promote the "backstab" method of installing wires in outlets and switches also...and we know how well that goes.

@RMDman - is this “backstabbing” an issue?? I just got 20 switches and outlets that I’m replacing! I bout this new Leviton push-click-connect ones: https://leviton.com/products/residential/decora-edge?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=resi_decora_edge_search&gad_source=1&gbraid=0AAAAADqU94-IYW6reuFnf2A8KWwTdrLST&gclid=Cj0KCQjwrp-3BhDgARIsAEWJ6Sza4rxCARH8YAdt5LfSFsZEX8O4JvGPph1ciVThkpOVxmlFNIh3DmsaApBNEALw_wcB Are they bad?

@ozhogin,  No I have used those before and they work well.  They are like the Wago connectors that have locks and not just "push in and hope" connectors.

Another option is to use a receptacle that doesn't have its own wires but has screw-to-clamp connections, such as this Leviton from Home Depot:

The key is the side screw connectors. Instead of the old style that requires a shepherd's hook, which is prone to improper installation, or a "back stab" which is unreliable, it lets you wire straight in (= easy) underneath the little metal plates under the screws. In fact, where the old receptacle allowed one per screw, so two hot and two neutral total, this allows two per screw, so up to 4 hot and 4 neutral!
As suggested in other answers, Wago-style connectors are a good alternative to wire nuts but, like wire nuts, you need to make sure they are UL or ETL listed. If you buy them from Home Depot/Lowes/local hardware store then there won't be a problem but a lot of online retailers ship stuff that looks nearly the same but is not the name brand and is not UL or ETL listed.
Box size can be an issue simply because a USB/receptacle takes more space than a simple receptacle. If you replace the box, go with metal.

Great advice thank you!
The outlet you linked is 25w, I have a bunch of them, they’re great, but I wanted to have one 60w in this location.

Another option would be to simply use Wago connectors instead of nuts.  You'd still want to pre-twist the stranded wires.


Wago has the distinct benefit of being impossible to install wrongly as long as the uninsulated section is 12mm (1/2").
